# Moving the files and databases from one server to other

Tags: linux, centos, putty, lamp, data-migration

I have to move my entire website with the source code , databases and other supporting software modules from one system to another. Both the systems have CentOs Operating system. Using putty I have to move the data. To be safe, I created a new user with root access Right now i have freshly installed LAMP and phpmyadmin on the newer system The configuration settings( httpd.conf , php.ini and various other unknown settings), file permissions, folder permissions and other things must be same.what are the steps to be followed to accomplish this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically use `rsync`. Having root user makes process even easier because you can guarantee to preserve permissions.

ssh into new Linux box and execute this `rsync` command:

> root@new-host# rsync -avl --delete --partial --progress root@old-host:/old/dir/ /new/dir/

used rsync flags meaning:

- `-a` - archive mode or recursive copy
- `-v` - verbose
- `-l` - preserve symlinks
- `--delete` - delete files on target which do not exist in source
- `--partial` - resume copy on huge files
- `--progress` - show progress indicator

This command will make sure that `/new/dir/` on new server is exactly the same as `/old/dir/` on old one. Beauty of `rsync` is that you can interrupt this command if your tree is huge, or execute it many times - each time it will work faster and get you closer to final goal of having two identical trees.

Comment: Thanks , how can i replicate the Lamp settings? what are the files that i need to edit?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to transfer successfully using scp command

The below command has to be executed from the source

scp -r  @:

-r  recursice file transfer

All permissions were retained